# gasLimit decrease over time

Tags: ubuntu, blockchain, ethereum, geth

I am deploying Ethereum over Ubuntu server. I initiated the blockchain with custom genesis.json parameters including gasLimit and difficulty level.

Over time, I noticed that difficulty keeps on adjusting itself by increasing and decreasing on every block generated. As for the gasLimit, it starts with the value I set and keeps on decreasing on every block until it reaches the default value of 4,712,388 which is less than my transaction cost and causing me issues.

Comment: Are you only specifying your desired gas limit in genesis.json or are you also passing it in when you start your miner(s)? For example, if you're using `geth`, are you also passing in `--targetgaslimit`?

Comment: The difficulty and gas limit is adjusted by the network. They will vary on each block.

Comment: @AdamKipnis am only specifying it on genesis.json file, I will try with --targetgaslimit while launching geth and share the results.

Comment: @Uahmed isn't there a way to control it? or at least put a minimum for gasLimit other than the default value?

Comment: @AdamKipnis setting the targetgaslimit is increasing the gasLimit value with every block generated, as it started with 20632083291593704 and now its 31423007890719372. I think this will solve my problem.. I will monitor this for the coming couple of days and mark this as the correct answer in case it worked. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I'll move my comments over to an answer.

Comment: @GhassanZein I am not sure about GasLimit but the difficulty plays important role in blockchain as the frequency of adding new block in the blockchain is manage by the difficulty and i dont think you can make it constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gasLimit` in the genesis block is only used as a starting point. As blocks are added to the chain, the block gas limit will change over time based on the miners processing the transactions on the network. To keep the block gas limit higher, you need to override the default configuration in your node client.

For [Parity](https://wiki.parity.io/Configuring-Parity):

> ```
> --gas-floor-target=[GAS]
>     Amount of gas per block to target when sealing a new block.
>     (default: 4700000)
>
> --gas-cap=[GAS]
>     A cap on how large we will raise the gas limit per block
>     due to transaction volume. (default: 6283184)
> ```

For [Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options):

> ```
> --targetgaslimit value    
>     Target gas limit sets the artificial target gas floor for the blocks to mine (default: 4712388)
> ```